# Подсчитать количество чисел, принадлежащих интервалу

Tags: python, олимпиада

необходимо подсчитать количество чисел в интервале от 222222222 до 333333333, которое при записи в хотя бы одной системе счисления с основанием от 2 до 36 состоит из нескольких одинаковых цифр.

```
count = 0 
for num in range(222222222, 333333334):
smooth = False
for base in range(2, 37):
    if len(set(str(num))) == 1:
        smooth = True
        break
if smooth:
    count += 1
print(count)
```

Comment: Ну подсчитай...

Comment: @Эникейщик спасибо, кэп очевидность, еще бы знать как код рабочий написать написать)  'count = 0
for num in range(222222222, 333333334):
    smooth = False
    for base in range(2, 37):
        if len(set(str(num))) == 1:
            smooth = True
            break
    if smooth:
        count += 1
print(count)'

А то только такая шляпа получается

Comment: Надо наверное не цикл брать от a до b, пытаясь переводить каждое число интервала по очереди в 30+ разных систем счисления, а от обратного пойти? Переводить в СС крайние значение в этого интервала, и смотреть, сколько туда впихать значений можно. Вы же знаете, что по условию вас для троичной системы например интересуют только варианты а-я 111 и 222. Условно если в какой-то СС нижняя граница это 576 а верхняя 5760, т проверять надо а-ля 666, 777, 1111, 2222, 3333, 4444, 5555. Формировать значения боле чем нижняя граница, и добавлять разряды пока влезают в верхнюю границу.

Comment: @Михаил, просто кода не хватит: напишите, что с ним не так.

Answer (score 0):

можно использовать многопоточность для ускорения процесса

```
import numpy as np
import concurrent.futures

def check(num):
    for base in range(2, 37):
        try:
            converted = np.base_repr(num, base)
            if len(set(converted)) == 1:
                return True
        except ValueError:
            continue
    return False

def main():
    count = 0
    with concurrent.futures.ThreadPoolExecutor() as executor:
        results = list(executor.map(check, range(222222222, 333333334)))
        count = results.count(True)
    print(count)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Comment: как вы думаете, зачем в вопросе тег Олимпиада?

Comment: Какой получился ответ?

Answer (score 0):

Вариант решения

```
def num_to_base(x, base):  # необязательная вспомогательная функция отображения числа в системах счисления
    s, zero = '', ord('0')
    while x:
        x, y = divmod(x, base)
        s += chr(y + zero + 7 * (y > 9))
    return s[::-1]


cnt, start, end = set(), 222222222, 333333333
for base in range(2, 37):  # перебираем системы счисления
    for num in range(1, base):  # перебираем цифры в системах счисления от 1 до base-1
        s = 0  # здесь будет формироваться число, записываемое одинаковыми цифрами для каждой из систем счисления
        while s <= end:  # цикл пока число не превысило верхнюю границу диапазона
            if s >= start:
                cnt.add(s)  # если число в диапазоне, добавляем его
                # print(f'Основание {base}: {num_to_base(s, base)}, десятичное: {s:_}')  # печать для наглядности
            s = s * base + num  # сдвигаем число на разряд влево и добавляем справа младший разряд
print(len(cnt))
```

Comment: @StanislavVolodarskiy ну да, согласен, нужно исключать повторы. Допилил, спасибо.

Answer (score 0):

Перебирать числа-кандидаты и проверять каждое - тупик. Их линейное количество, а количество найденых - логарифмическое. Ещё одна причина - порождать числа из одинаковых цифр значительно проще чем проверять числа на "одинаковоциферность".

Генератор `repunits(base)` возвращает бесконечную последовательность [репьюнитов](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A0%D0%B5%D0%BF%D1%8C%D1%8E%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%82%D1%8B) в указаной системе счисления: *1<sub>base</sub>, 11<sub>base</sub>, 111<sub>base</sub>, ...*.

Генератор `repdigits(base)` возвращает бесконечную последовательность [репдиджитов](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A0%D0%B5%D0%BF%D0%B4%D0%B8%D0%B4%D0%B6%D0%B8%D1%82%D1%8B).

Функция `count_repdigits(low, high)` составляет множество репдиджитов для оснований от *2* до *36* в интервале *[low, high]* и возвращает его размер.

```
def repunits(base):
    n = 0
    while True:
        n = base * n + 1
        yield n


def repdigits(base):
    for n in repunits(base):
        yield from range(n, base * n, n)


def count_repdigits(low, high):
    s = set()
    for base in range(2, 36 + 1):
        for n in repdigits(base):
            if high < n:
                break
            if low <= n:
                s.add(n)
    return len(s)


print(count_repdigits(222222222, 333333333))
```

> ```
> $ python count_repdigits.py
> 87
> ```